# Change highlight colors in minted

Tags: latex, syntax-highlighting, pygments

I was setting up a nice environment to present my code in printed documentations. First I was using the lstlisting package for Latex but then I stumbled upon **minted**.

minted is really great, but is there a way to **change the highlight colors**?

Since minted uses the Pygments library, I assume Pygments is the key to the color, but I haven't found it yet.

Could anyone explain how it can be done or post a link that shows how it's done?

[image: minted highlighted output]

Answer (score 19, accepted):

You want

```
\usemintedstyle{<name>}
```

where you can get `<name>` by doing

```
pygmentize -L styles
```

at the command prompt/terminal. For example, the `minted` documentation itself uses the `trac` style.

Comment: Great. I found some nice styles, but I think I will try to customize them a litte (as shows here http://pygments.org/docs/styles). Thank you!

Comment: To try out pygments, the [pygments demo website](https://pygments.org/demo/) can be used.